# What does the connerDb method stands for?

Tags: java, database-connection

Can anyone help me understand the meaning of ConnerDb method?

```
    public class Login_frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    public Login_frame() {
    initComponents();       
    conn=javaconnect.connerDb();
    }
```

Comment: What is `javaconnect`?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out!

Comment: Well, where is it declared? What is its type? I interpret your question as asking what `connerDb()` is, not what `javaconnect` is.